# use clickable span in list view item

Tags: android, listview, cpu-word, clickable

i want clickable word in listview what use for this i use clickable span but not work 
please help me

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {




        TextView ocTextTitle =(TextView)ocHolder.txtTitle;


        if ( ocTextType.getText().equals("d") )
        {
            if ( isOnline.equals("1") )
            {
                   Intent intent = new Intent ( ChildList.this, loginTwo.class );
        intent.putExtra ( "TextBox",ocTextTitle.getText().toString()  );
        startActivity(intent);


            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to click alphabet from work "TEST"-"T"

Comment: did you setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) ?

Comment: i want clickable word in list view

Comment: did you setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) ?

Comment: no, but i dont know what is movementmethod

Comment: thanks for good help , how can i hide underline in spanable string

Comment: i want all word in list view is clickable but i dont like underline in word 

i want when i click on word go to search activity 
item in list view fill with webservice

Comment: Please see my answer here [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33076047/2581109)

Comment: Please see my answer here, it will make list item clickable [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33076047/2581109](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33076047/2581109)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom adapter for the listview, try below one in getView method.

```
String title = ocHolder.ocTextType.getText();
    holder.TV_userLevel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (title != null && title.equals("d") )
            {
                if ( isOnline.equals("1") )
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent ( mContext, loginTwo.class );
                    intent.putExtra ( "TextBox",title);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what use custom adapter i want clickable word in list view